# How to find replacements of CSS 2.1 properties missing in CSS 3?

Tags: css

The W3C maintains an excellent list of [all CSS properties, both current and proposed](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/all-properties.en.html). Of the 115 properties marked as CSS 2.1, sixteen of these are *not* part of any CSS module (for level 3 and above). These are:

> azimuth,
>   elevation,
>   line-height,
>   page-break-after,
>   page-break-before,
>   page-break-inside,
>   pitch,
>   pitch-range,
>   play-during,
>   richness,
>   speak-header,
>   speak-numeral,
>   speak-punctuation,
>   speech-rate,
>   stress,
>   volume

Now I'm aware of the W3C statement, from [CSS Snapshot 2015](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-2015/#css-levels) that states "Each module adds functionality and/or replaces part of the CSS2.1 specification. The CSS Working Group intends that the new CSS modules will not contradict the CSS2.1 specification: only that they will add functionality and refine definitions." However there seems to be no upgrade path or list of deprecated properties.

I'm pretty sure modern browsers, will, for backward-compatibility reasons, choose to honor the well-defined and stable CSS 2.1 properties. But someone (perhaps the folks in charge of a particular module) decided that the CSS 2.1 properties were clunky, hacks, or otherwise did not fit into the clean world of CSS 3 modules.

For example, I searched the [CSS Speech Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/) looking to see whether `speak-numeral` (one of the missing 16) was mentioned. It wasn't, but I found `speak-as` which appears to capture the same functionality.

So the programming and programming-related questions here are:

1. Why are these 16 properties not marked deprecated?
2. Is there an "upgrading to CSS3" guide somewhere?
3. What is the appropriate strategy for new web applications? Do we continue to use these old properties until the module makes Recommendation status and/or they get better browser support? Is it a good idea to use *both* properties (old and new) in a style sheet?

Comment: The entire aural section of CSS2.1 is informative, so as far as CSS2.1 is concerned they're not part of the normative spec (and user agents were never required to implement them to conform to CSS2.1). The Speech module states plainly that the aural media type (and everything associated with it) is indeed deprecated. Note that the list of all CSS properties is automatically generated, as stated on the page itself, and if I'm not wrong it's pulling from either an internal document, or the property index on the public document (which itself is also informative).

Comment: Excellent info...guess I didn't read the 2.1 spec closely enough to see the aural styles sections was not normative.

Comment: @BoltClock - I hadn't picked up that that the aural section is not normative either. It makes me wonder what the point of retaining it in CSS 2.2 is. Do you know if there were ever any working implementations?

Comment: @Alohci: There are no known implementations in any mainstream layout engines (not even in Presto), but an accessibility tool called [Emacspeak](http://emacspeak.sourceforge.net) touts "full support for W3C's Aural CSS (ACSS)" (and is in active development - version 45 was just released [*today*](https://github.com/tvraman/emacspeak/releases/tag/45.0)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take one example, I suspect by far the most commonly used of those listed, `line-height`.

The [CSS Inline Layout Module Level 3, Section 2. Line Heights and Baseline Alignment](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#line-height) says

> This section is being rewritten. Refer to section 10.8 of [CSS2] for
>   the normative CSS definition or the 2002 Working Draft if you want
>   pretty pictures. (But ignore the old text, half of it’s wrong. We’re
>   not specifying which half, that’s to be determined.) The CSS2
>   specification should be used as the guideline for implementation.

So it's not deprecated, it's just that the description from level 2.2 holds until such time that a level 3 definition can be written. Level 3 is huge, and work has to be prioritized. Line-height obviously works well enough for that priority to be low. No doubt, it will be addressed eventually.

The others are probably similar. Their level 2 definitions have simply not yet been superseded.

Comment: Considering the question was posted more than 2 hours ago, and the answer doesn't take *that* long to figure out, I don't think Alohci was trying to compete with anyone, at all.

Comment: With the exception of page-break-after, page-break-before and page-break-inside, which are paged media properties, the rest of the properties listed are from the old aural styles section, which *have* been superseded by the Speech module.

Comment: This is great. I like the answer "just not there yet" but given the age of CSS3 I would have thought that the 2.1 properties were at least covered. I'll look more through the Paged Media modules and Generated Content for Paged Media modules. It may make sense to rename the breaking properties given the sophistication of the new modules, I guess, but I was surprised to see them missing.